# When using the combining schema as the parent schema: Could not resolve schema reference '#foo'. Path 'not.allOf[0]'

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema, ref

Consider an example in
https://github.com/json-schema-org/JSON-Schema-Test-Suite/blob/master/tests/draft6/ref.json#L414

the original schema is:

```
{
      "allOf": [{
           "$ref": "http://localhost:1234/bar#foo"
       }],
       "definitions": {
            "A": {
                "$id": "http://localhost:1234/bar#foo",
                "type": "integer"
             }
       }
}
```

which is valid.

For this schema S, if I want to create a new schema by adding a combining schema outside this schema, like: `{"not":S}`, which is:

```
{
     "not": {
         "allOf": [{
              "$ref": "http://localhost:1234/bar#foo"
          }],
          "definitions": {
               "A": {
                   "$id": "http://localhost:1234/bar#foo",
                   "type": "integer"
                }
          }
      }
}
```

with the Location-independent identifier with absolute URI, also use `$id`. But it is invalid.

The error message(using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/):

```
Error parsing schema
Message:
Error when resolving schema reference 'http://localhost:1234/bar#foo'. Path 'not.allOf[0]', line 3, position 20.
```

A similar example is:

```
{
    "not": {
         "allOf": [{
               "$ref": "#foo"
          }],
          "definitions": {
                "A": {
                     "$id": "#foo",
                     "type": "integer"
                }
           }
     }
}
```

with the Location-independent identifier, is also invalid.

I cannot figure out why it is invalid after adding a parent schema if there are `$ref` and `$id` at the same time...

Here `{"not":S}` is just one possibility, also can consider `{"anyOf":[{S}]}`.

I know that `$id` declares a base URI against which $ref URI-references are resolved.

But what is the problem with the above schemas?
And how should I correct them?

I will so appreciate it if someone helps me out...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct here, and your schema is correct. I would call this a bug in the implementation.

Your schema is valid for JSON Schema `draft-07`, but not JSON Schema draft `2019-09` or above. For `2019-09` and above, your `$id` value can't contain a non-empty fragment.

You can see the correct and valid behaviour on another web based validator, a web based version of the HyperJump validator: https://json-schema.hyperjump.io

This web based implementation defaults to latest (2020-12), but you can specify a draft version using `$schema` (for example `"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#"`).

To see this working on HyperJump, either modify your schema to remove fragments in the identifier URIs, or specify that you're using `draft-07`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Yeah, you are right, they are valid in HyperJump validator with the right draft version. I tested another schema that should be invalid, but it returns valid... So I am confused that how much can I trust this validator...?  Thanks again! :D

Comment: I'm pretty confident you can trust it. If you'd like help with that other schema, feel free to join our open Slack server. The guy who wrote HyperJump is one of our most active and knowledgeable members.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!